# What was the salary of an IMF agent?

Tags: mission-impossible, mission-impossible-1996

In Mission Impossible 1, Ethan is being suspected of being a mole because his dad's farm has $127,000 in their bank account.

A high-end programmer, among other jobs, make close to that much in a year and they do not have such great skills as Ethan.

One would think that someone as good as him wouldn't become a mole over $127k.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [script online](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Mission-Impossible.html):

> ```
>                      KITTRIDGE (CONT'D) 
>            I want to show you something, Ethan. 
>
> He now shoves the papers across the table.  They're xeroxed 
> copies of a Wisconsin bank account in the name of DONALD and 
> MARGARET ETHAN HUNT.  It shows a balance of $127, 000. 
>
>                      KITTRIDGE (CONT'D) 
>            Since your father's death, your family's 
>            farm has been in sub-chapter S and now, 
>            suddenly, they're flush with over a 
>            hundred and twenty grand in the bank. 
>            Dad's illness was supposed to have wiped 
>            out the bank account -- dying slowly in 
>            America after all, can be a very 
>            expensive proposition Ethan.  So, why 
>            don't we go quietly out of here onto the 
>            plane...
> ```

So what appears to have raised the suspicion of IMF is that Ethan's father had died after a long illness and that his mother should have only had very little money in her bank account and the farm she owned with his father is bankrupt.

At no point is it implied that IMF think that this is the sole money that Ethan as the suspected mole in IMF has received. The NOC list that is at the center of the plot in the movie is worth millions.

The fact that Ethan's mother, a poor widow, suddenly has a large amount of money in her checking account is just a piece of evidence they are using **along with** the fact that Ethan was apparently the only agent to survive a botched mission.  Yes, perhaps Ethan does earn enough money to be able to support his Mother - but enough to gift her over $120k?  As far as IMF are concerned this piece evidence is suspicious and enough to want to detain Ethan for more questioning.

Later in the script:

> ```
>       PHELPS
>            ..when you think about it, Ethan, it was
>            inevitable..no more Cold War.  No more
>            secrets you keep from everyone but
>            yourself, operations you answer to no one
>            but yourself.  Then one morning you wake
>            up and find out the President of the
>            United States is running the country -
>            without your permission.  The son-of-a-
>            bitch!  How dare he?  You realize itís
>            over, youíre an obsolete piece of
>            hardware not worth upgrading, youíve got
>            a lousy marriage and sixty-two grand a 
>            year.  Kittridge, weíll go after that no
>            good son-of-a-bitch, big time!
> ```

So Phelps, Ethan's team-leader in IMF earns $62,000 a year, so it is likely that Ethan earns less than this.  This is probably in line with a 'high end programmer' in 1996 - but one imagines that agents like Ethan (or James Bond or ... name any fictional spy) are probably not in this for the money, but they are somehow attracted to the danger, challenge and jet-setting lifestyle.

Comment: I see. Latter Jim Phelp says that he's on $62k salary per year though.

Comment: @JimThio - good find. This was in 1996 and these are government employees. So Ethen was probably on less than that, which makes his mother suddenly getting 127k very suspicious. I've edited the answer to include this.

Comment: Hah, just saw this scene and this question sprang into my mind. But you already answered it well, although it was actually *Kittridge* who *Jim* was talking about in that moment and who earns 62,000 a year, and who is even higher in the hierarchy.

Comment: @ChristianRau - good point.

Comment: If I can climb building, swing from ropes, prevent ww3 I would demand at least $1 billion a year. I mean those are risky jobs and well, I provide reasonable value there. A few seconds late and we have WW3.

Answer (score 4):

Well from the opening scene of MI1, it shows that Ethan Hunt’s pay grade in 1996 is GS-17, Grade 9.

[image]
From Wikipedia I knew that there were three GS "supergrades" (GS-16, GS-17 and GS-18)in the US.

Also, the highest grade nowadays is GS-15 and I think maybe it worths GS-14 Grade 9 in 2019, which’s $111640/year.

Answer (score 1):

In the opening credits of MI-1, it briefly flashes a Govt Civil Service ID card for Ethan Hunt. And, I think it lists his pay grade as GS-12; but, not a step level. That would put his 1996 annual salary around $43-51,000. That's a heck of a lot of risk for a meager 5 digits.

Comment: Welcome!  Do you have a source for this information?

Comment: @steeler they are referring to the General Schedule pay rate system of the US government employee.